# Setting the input type to be a number makes the input width shorter

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox, input-field

I'm using wordpress plugin for forms by Contact Form 7. There is almost no styling, just simple display: flex; set so I could have two inputs in one row taking 50% width each total 100% of parent container. However, when I change one input type to be number instead of text, that input shrinks down and becomes much shorter and I have this weird spacing. I tried many things, changing display, width, paddings, what so ever, but nothing helps. The only thing that makes that number input bigger is setting fixed width for input[type=number] but that's not what I need, I need the flex display to do all the work and make each field take 50% on all screen sizes.

Am I missing something? Why is it that number field acts so weird?

This is how it looks with number input type being set:

[image]

```
div.wpcf7 {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.wpcf7-form input {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

<section id="text-6" class="widget widget_text">            <div class="textwidget"><div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f231-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form action="/wordpress/#wpcf7-f231-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="231"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.9.2"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f231-o1"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_container_post" value="0">
</div>
<div class="first-group">
<label><br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text form-control" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Your name here"></span> </label><p></p>
<p><label><br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Organisation"></span> </label>
</p></div>
<p><label> Area of interest<br>
   <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-country"><select name="your-country" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select form-control" aria-invalid="false"><option value="Equipment">Equipment</option><option value="Sell">Sell</option><option value="Buy">Buy</option></select></span></label></p>
<div class="second-group">
<label> Contact me by:<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><input type="number" name="your-message" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-number wpcf7-validates-as-number form-control" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Phone:"></span> </label><br>
<label><br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><input type="email" name="your-email" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Email:"></span> </label>
</div>
<div class="contact_cta"><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit btn btn-primary"><span class="ajax-loader"></span></div>
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Please edit the post and paste your HTML here, so people are able to help better. Thanks!

Comment: @RoniLaukkarinen My bad, here you go. Edited.

Comment: You need to use `width: 50%`, to override their default

Comment: @LGSon width on the number input itself? In that case it becomes even shorter

Comment: If you update the question with a _working_ code snippet, that reproduce the issue you describe, we will be able to provide a proper answer. I also reopened the question.

Comment: I solved the problem with flex-basis: 100% for the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the input field listen to the parent `flex` container by setting the input to `flex-basis: 100%`. This way it takes all the available space of the `flex` parent element.

The reason why `input[type=number]` wasn't taking full available width in the first place as compared to `input[type=text]` I believe was because the number input size attribute is not allowed, so you have to declare it yourself in CSS, like `width: 100%`.